# Rails find at least one "order" with status "completed"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find

Not the best with Rails so this might be very simple.
I have a database with tables `Groups and Orders` - `groups has_many orders, orders belongs_to groups.` Orders have a string field called `status`, which can be `in progress, canceled, completed`. An order is considered "not in progress" when it is either canceled or completed.
I would like to be able to find all groups with no orders in progress and at least one order completed. So far I have the none in progress:

```
groups = Group.find(:all, :include => :orders, :conditions => ["orders.status != :in_progress", { :in_progress => Constant::IN_PROGRESS }])
```

Is there a way to find groups with at least one order completed (without simply iterating over this array and picking them out)?

Edit: Rails version 2.1.0 Sorry for the oversight!

Comment: 2.1.0 - sorry for forgetting that, added to original question.

Answer (score 0):

If you put this into one find condition it's going to be really complicated and you will probably want to add more filters later so might want to break it into to finds.

```
@groups = []
groups = Group.find(:all, :joins => :orders, :conditions =>])
no_orders_in_progress = Group.find(:all, :jois => 'order', :conditions => ['status!=', 'in progress'], :limit => 5)
orders_completed = Group.find(:all, :joins => 'order', :conditions => ['status=?', 'completed'], :limit => 1)
@groups << orders_completed + no_orders_in_progress
```

Make sure to limit it however many you want.

Comment: If you are using R3 then let me know I will post the syntax for that but it looks like you are using <R3

Comment: Maybe I'm just dense, but doesn't this just give me an array with the two arrays in it, one with completed items and one with in progress items? I'm not seeing how to use this to see if a group has at least one completed and none left in progress. Let me know if I misunderstood!

Comment: Yeah, I changed it so that it's just one array.

Comment: I really have no idea what your trying to do in terms of finding groups.

Comment: `I would like to be able to find all groups with no orders in progress and at least one order completed` what does this mean and why? The code I wrote finds all groups with no orders, which I take it to mean not in progress, and then one completed, then combines these arrays.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. Groups always have at least one order, which starts in progress, and then can be canceled or completed. So Group A has 1 canceled and one completed order; Group B has 2 canceled orders. They both have orders "not in progress", but only Group A is considered "completed", having at least one order with status 'completed'. Unless I'm mistaken, your code would combine all groups with orders not in progress (which means canceled or completed), and then all groups with completed orders (which might be duplicates from the first query)...

Comment: (out of room)... and wouldn't exclude groups with no completed orders. For now, the best solution I've come up with is to find all groups with orders not in progress, then loop through those and create a new array with only groups that have a completed order. Hope this is clearer.